# For Loop Matrix Error

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, addition

I am writing some Matlab code to analyze spikes and their stimuli. In the first part of the code I get the timing of a spike and then find the frame that was shown on the screen just prior. I then want to take the image data from that frame and add it to my own movie data. The x and y components of `myMovie` and `moviedata` are both 128x128, however when I try to add the image values from a certain frame from the stimuli `moviedata(:,:,j)` to a specific frame in my movie `myMovie(:,:,k)` I get "error: matrix dimensions must agree". Is there any way to fix this?

Code:

```
for n=1:1100

   t = blocks(5).spikes{1}(:,n);

   for k=1:25
       ind = find(round(double(blocks(5).frameEpocs*1000)/1000) == (t-(1/(25*10))));
       j = blocks(5).frameEpocs(1,ind);
       myMovie(:,:,k) = myMovie(:,:,k) + double(moviedata(:,:,j));
   end

end
```

Comment: It could be the fact that `find` is finding **more than one** value that satisfies the condition within the function.  Try finding just **one** value by doing `ind = find(..., 1);`, specifying a second parameter of 1 to find just one match.  Use some print debug statements and see what `j` is.  My gut feeling is that `j` is more than one value, and so when you are trying to reference your `moviedata` structure, you are accessing **more than one slice**, which is why you're getting the dimensions error.  **Also:** are `myMovie` and `moviedata` **both** 3D matrices?

Comment: Adding the parameter to `find` still results in the error message. `myMovie` is 128x128x25 while `moviedata` is 128x128x18000.

Comment: Are you **sure** that `j` gives you a **single** value?  That's the only place in your code that would allow MATLAB to give you that error.

Comment: I say only one thing [debug](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/debugging-code.html). This should solve be the best way of solving the problem. Further, the codes seems unstable. As said earlier, `find` will return all the values fulfilling the criterion. If find would return more than one value here and you only expect one value to be returned, you should consider if something is wrong with the rest of your code. If find only returns one value, then you must check the sizes of your matrices with the debugger. Also, is `j` an integer value smaller than 18000?

Comment: Some other things, if `j` is an integer, why is the rounding necessary? Is `(t-(1/(25*10)))` ever an integer value? Does `t` have a finite decimal value? Otherwise you would never find anything. The time stamp seems to come from your device, but this does not necessary mean that is a multiple of 1/f, where f is the sample frequency of your device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` may return an empty matrix and hence `j` would be empty as well.
In that case, the command `myMovie(:,:,k) + double(moviedata(:,:,j));` attempts to add a 128x128x1 matrix with a 128x128x0 matrix and thus the error you got.